# Root access to cloudcontrol

Tags: cloudcontrol

I need to configure ioncube on cloudcontrol. How do I get a root access to my container. Is this only possible with a paid up account? I tried using the command line but could not be able to get root access to the container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To install ioncube, you have to provide the ioncube extension as part of your repository and use the buildpacks custom PHP.ini feature to load the extension. Check the README for instructions how to do this. https://github.com/cloudControl/buildpack-php/blob/master/README.md